# Function to append modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have 3 modals that all have the same format and are activated by different onclicks (Create Contact, Update Contact, Delete Contact). I am wanting the modal-title and modal-body to change depending on which button was clicked. How would I go about creating a function that appends the modal content depending on which button was clicked? Thank you for your help!

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Contact Created!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use `this` and get the `class/id` of the element and then maybe use some if statements to alter the content

Answer (score 0):

I have written the JavaScript "BootstrapModel" class for the same purpose.

It also depends on jQuery so don't forget to embed jQuery before using this class.

class is :

```
var BootstrapModal = (function (options) {
var defaults = {
    modalId: "#confirmModal",
    btnClose: "#btnClose",
    title: "Confirm",
    content: "Some bootstrap content",
    onClose: function () {
    },
    onSave: function () {
    }
};

defaults = options || defaults;

var $modalObj = $(defaults.modalId);

var hideModal = function () {
    $modalObj.modal("hide");
};

var showModal = function () {
    $modalObj.modal("show");
};

var updateModalTitle = function (title) {
    defaults.title = title;
    //$($modalObj).find(".modal-title").eq(0).html(title);
    $modalObj.find(".modal-title").eq(0).html(title);
};

var updateModalBody = function (content) {
    defaults.content = content;
    $modalObj.find(".modal-body").eq(0).html(content);
};

return {
    getDefaults: function () {
        return defaults;
    },
    hide: function () {
        hideModal();
    },
    show: function () {
        showModal();
    },
    updateTitle: function (title) {
        updateModalTitle(title);
        return this;
    },
    updateBody: function (body) {
        updateModalBody(body);
        return this;
    }
}
});
```

Usage :

```
var emailModal = new BootstrapModal({modalId: "#confirmModal"});

emailModal.updateTitle("Mail sent successfully").updateBody("<br/>This box will automatically close after 3 seconds.").show();
// Hide the Modal
emailModal.hide();
```

HTML Structure for the Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="thankyouModal" aria-hidden="true" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="padding-top: 225px">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="thankyouModal">Thank you</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Thank you. We'll let you know once we are up.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this is by loading the data in from external files. So you'd have your initial declaration of your modal box (just the surrounding div), and then in each file you have the containing code for the rest of the modal, then use a bit of jQuery to fire them off:

HTML (in main file)

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-results" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#create-contact').click(function(){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#modal-results").html('create-contact.html');
  $("#modal-results").modal('show');
});
```